# Controlling both angles of a Ray

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I'm new to Unity and have a problem I can't figure out. I want objects to spawn randomly at a distance of 20 from a FPS player. You could say the objects need to spawn on the surface of a half sphere with the player as the center. But: not all of that sphere can be used. The "highest" part is too high for objects to spawn, so basically it's a sphere with the top cut off.

**What I tried:**

```
thePosition = Random.onUnitSphere * 20 + object2.transform.position;
```

Obviously, this takes into account the whole sphere (should be only half a sphere) and doesn't take into account the "cut off" part.

So I thought: I basically want to make a ray that can pivot on the ground (so the max angle is 360°), and can go up and down, with a max angle of 90°. Think of it like a canon that can turn (pivot) and go up/down with an angle. Here's an image of what I mean: [image: sketch]

**So I tried:**

```
Vector3 raydirection = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 0);      
raydirection = Quaternion.Euler (45, 0, 0) * raydirection;
Ray ray = new Ray (player.transform.position, raydirection);     
thePosition = ray.GetPoint (20);
```

But that doesn't allow me to control the pivot angle (angle 1) and the "up-down" angle (angle 2) separately.

So **my question** is: how can I make it so that I can control both angles of this ray? Because if I can do that, I can just take a random number between 0 and 360 for the pivoting part, and between 0 and 90 for the up/down part.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Take a random point on the sphere, `Math.abs` the Y value?

Comment: That wouldn't work, since it has to be a sphere with the top cut off.

Comment: You want your upward angle limited to 90 degrees and your horizontal angle limited by 360. This is a full half-sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, I needed something very similar to this. The following Behavior will spawn a certain prefab (`objectToSpawn`) exactly `spawnCount` times within the set parameters.

The helper class (bottom code) generates a Vector from Yaw, Pitch and a Vector (basically the distance in your case).

What it does:

- Pick a random direction (yaw and pitch) within set parameters
- Pick a random distance (sounds like you can omit this step)
- Calculate the vector
- Spawn object

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject objectToSpawn;

    public int spawnCount;

    public float minDistance = 2;
    public float maxDistance = 10;

    public float minPitchDegrees = 0;
    public float maxPitchDegrees = 45;

    public float minYawDegrees = -180;
    public float maxYawDegrees = 180;

    void Start () 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spawnCount; i++) 
        {
            float distance = minDistance + Random.value * (maxDistance - minDistance);
            float yaw = minYawDegrees + Random.value * (maxYawDegrees - minYawDegrees);
            float pitch = minPitchDegrees + Random.value * (maxPitchDegrees - minPitchDegrees);

            Vector3 position = RotationHelper.ConvertYawPitch (Vector3.forward * distance, yaw, pitch);

            Instantiate (objectToSpawn, position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class RotationHelper {

    public static Vector3 ConvertYawPitch(Vector3 vector, float yaw, float pitch)
    {
        Quaternion yawRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (yaw, Vector3.up);
        Vector3 yawedZAxis = yawRotation * Vector3.left;

        Quaternion pitchRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (pitch, yawedZAxis);
        Vector3 yawedVector = yawRotation * vector;

        Vector3 position = pitchRotation * yawedVector;

        return position;
    }
}
```

In your specific case, the parameters should be:

- `minDistance` = 20
- `maxDistance` = 20
- `minPitchDegrees` = 0
- `maxPitchDegrees` = 0-90, whatever the angle is after you "cut off the top"
- `minYawDegrees` = -180
- `maxYawDegrees` = 180

Comment: Because OP used `Random.onUnitSphere`, I believe the original intent was to generate a *uniform* distribution of points, although I may be wrong and this particular detail could be irrelevant

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I think it is, *"I want objects to spawn randomly"* seems to be the main point (including the mentioned restrictions of course).

Comment: Great! Thanks. One question, why not simply use: `float yaw = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minYawDegrees, maxYawDegrees);`? Same question for pitch.

Answer (score 2):

> I want objects to spawn randomly at a distance of 20 from a FPS
>   player.

What I understood from this is that you want to spawn objects on the ground, distant 20 units away from the player, in random directions.

> You could say the objects need to spawn on the surface of a half
>   sphere with the player as the center.

Now, this is just another way to make things complex. No need to use the sphere to solve this.

**If** you want to spawn objects on the surface, easiest solution will be to get a random angle in relation with `Vector3.up` and walk for 20 units to find the desired point.

**Script:**

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform prefab;

    [Range(10,50)]
    public float distance = 20f;


    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
            Spawn();
        }
    }

    [ContextMenu("Spawn")]
    public void Spawn()
    {
        Vector3 spawnPoint = FindPoint(player.position, distance, Random.Range(0, 360));
        Instantiate(prefab, spawnPoint, Quaternion.identity, transform);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Clear")]
    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var item in transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            if (item != transform)
                DestroyImmediate(item.gameObject);
        }
    }

    Vector3 FindPoint(Vector3 center, float radius, int angle)
    {
        return center + Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up) * (Vector3.right * radius);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Calculates random point based on player's position:

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I like the animated gif